# SQL statement with a master detailt, getting only 3 details

Tags: sql-server, master-detail

A question in SQL that can help me? I have a master table called products, another one called prices (where it is one to many depending on supplier prices), that is, the query is like this

```
SELECT 
    p.id_empresa, p.codigo, p.descripcion, p.piezas_comprar,
    IIF(o.Costo IS NULL, 0, o.Costo) AS Costo, 
    IIF(r.Nombre IS NULL, 'S/P', r.Nombre) AS Proveedor, 
    IIF(r.Calificacion IS NULL, 0, r.Calificacion) AS Calificacion 
FROM 
    vw_productos_compras p 
LEFT JOIN
    access_pyme.dbo.Productos_Proveedores o ON p.Codigo = o.Codigo 
                                            AND p.id_empresa = o.id_empresa 
LEFT JOIN 
    access_pyme.dbo.Proveedores r ON o.id_proveedor = r.id_poveedor
```

I need only three records per supplier, that is, from the Suppliers table, only the three ordered by the cost of their product table, alias or

3 product records 1, 3 product records 2, 3 product records 3

```
00001 Supplier X $10
00001 Supplier Y $11
00001 Supplier Z $12
00002 Supplier X $8 
00002 Supplier Y $7 
00002 Supplier Z $9
00003 Supplier X $16
00003 Supplier Y $15
00003 Supplier Z $14
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: So what does the query you have right now return, and what do you want it to look like? I see you included a result there, but it's not clear what that's derived from or whether that's your starting point or desired end point.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer, use Outer Apply:

```
SELECT p.id_empresa, p.codigo, p.descripcion, p.piezas_comprar,
iif(o.Costo IS NULL, 0, o.Costo) AS Costo, iif(r.Nombre IS NULL,
'S/P', r.Nombre) AS Proveedor, iif(r.Calificacion IS NULL, 0,
r.Calificacion) AS Calificacion 
FROM            vw_productos_compras p

/*LEFT JOIN access_pyme.dbo.Productos_Proveedores o ON p.Codigo =
o.Codigo AND p.id_empresa = o.id_empresa */ 

OUTER APPLY  (   
  SELECT
 top 3 id_proveedor, Costo   
 FROM access_pyme.dbo.Productos_Proveedores o   
 WHERE p.Codigo = o.Codigo AND p.id_empresa = o.id_empresa ) o 

LEFT JOIN access_pyme.dbo.Proveedores r ON o.id_proveedor = r.id_poveedor
```